# subprocess.run while running as systemd service

Tags: python, systemd

I have Python script which is run periodically (with the help of systemd timer). It performs some checks and in case of need sends me e-mail with the help of DMA. Internally I use `subprocess.run()` to call `mail` Linux command:

```
body = str("Something is wrong")
subprocess.run(["mail", "-s", "[myscript@myserver] - ALERT", "mymail@domain.com"], input = body.encode())
```

AFAIK `subprocess.run()` should wait until `mail` incantation will finish. Internally `mail` calls `sendmail` which is provided by DMA. And I've noticed strange behavior: when I call my script directly from command line I can check in `journalctl -r` that my mail is actually forwarded to the DMA and successfully sent to mymail@domain.com:

```
Jun 17 17:00:59 myserver dma[859]: <mymail@domain.com> delivery successful
Jun 17 17:00:57 myserver dma[859]: using SMTP authentication for user mymail
Jun 17 17:00:57 myserver dma[859]:   Server supports LOGIN authentication
Jun 17 17:00:57 myserver dma[859]:   Server does not support STARTTLS
Jun 17 17:00:57 myserver dma[859]: Server greeting successfully completed
Jun 17 17:00:57 myserver dma[859]: SSL initialization successful
Jun 17 17:00:57 myserver dma[859]:   Server supports STARTTLS
Jun 17 17:00:57 myserver dma[859]: Server greeting successfully completed
Jun 17 17:00:57 myserver dma[859]: trying remote delivery to smtp.domain.com [AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD] pref 0
Jun 17 17:00:57 myserver dma[859]: using smarthost (smtp.domain.com:587)
Jun 17 17:00:57 myserver dma[859]: <mymail@domain.com> trying delivery
Jun 17 17:00:57 myserver dma[858]: mail to=<mymail@domain.com> queued as b40adc.5577f82d5a80
Jun 17 17:00:57 myserver dma[858]: new mail from user=root uid=8 envelope_from=<mymail@domain.com>
```

But when the same script is called by systemd timer the `dma` process hangs in the middle and the mail is left in spool:

```
Jun 17 18:00:16 myserver dma[9078]: trying remote delivery to smtp.domain.com [AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD] pref 0
Jun 17 18:00:16 myserver dma[9078]: using smarthost (smtp.domain.com:587)
Jun 17 18:00:16 myserver dma[9078]: <mymail@domain.com> trying delivery
Jun 17 18:00:16 myserver dma[9077]: mail to=<mymail@domain.com> queued as b404d6.55e1c6b52a80
Jun 17 18:00:16 myserver dma[9077]: new mail from user=root uid=8 envelope_from=<mymail@domain.com>
```

I've thought that it may be because of parent script finishes before mail was sent so I've added 10-seconds `sleep()` just after `subprocess.run()` incantation and that worked fine!

So I wonder why this happens and how it can be worked-out in a right way withou tricks with `sleep()`?

Comment: Are you sure *the `sendmail` binary* provided by DMA waits for delivery to finish? (It sounds like it delivers synchronously like exim, without queueing. Does dma have an option to just queue the message and let a separate dma daemon handle it, postfix-style?) I strongly suspect `sendmail` forks off a delivery process and then immediately exits, making the parent `mail` _think_ it's done and exiting as well. You could try adding a `syslog.syslog(LOG_INFO, "subprocess.run has exited")` after the call to see where it shows up in your journal.

Comment: Yep, that can be the cause. Thank you for suggestion. So, if it forks and then calling process kills main instance then forked off child will die too, right?